# Help finding PWM IC with marking on device '0L346' not sure whether it starts with 0 or O. package of device is sot23-6

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, identification

[image]
I was troubleshooting my mobile charger where I found PWM IC faulty.
However I couldn't find it's datasheet for ordering information.

The device marking is 'OL346' not sure if it starts with numeric 0 or alphabet O.

The package of this device is sot23-6.

Please help me finding this device name.

Comment: I know of a commonly available 6 pin SOT23 device that takes a voltage input and outputs a PWM waveform but it doesn't have the marking you specify so maybe try and give more circuitry details or provide a good picture.

Comment: Andy, the IC I'm talking about is the one which I have circled with red.

Comment: If you are really lucky it may match up with the LTC6992 from linear tech - maybe try and investigate the likely pin connections to see if it makes sense.

Comment: What makes you think that's a 'PWM IC' and not a SMPSU Controller?

Comment: The terms "PWM IC" and "SMPS controller" are often used interchangeably in industry. Quite often the main controller is just referred to as "the PWM" even if it's a variable-frequency design :)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly OB2262. Normaly very easy to find same or equal this kind of sot23-6 type pwm ics. Check out also Fairchild web page product catalog. First star to to compare with GND, Vdd , Fb pins and after some try u will find same or equal.

Comment: Doesn't match the package marking.

Answer (score 0):

Code : 0L

Device: MUN5134DW1

Manufacturer:  Motorolla

Base: DO = [image: The DO Package from http://www.marsport.org.uk]

Pakage SOT363

Device Type: dual pnp dtr 22k+47k

Comment: Wrong package. Not a PWM controller.